# Rename [lego-star-wars-3] to [lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I'd like to propose renaming the tag for Lego Star Wars III: The Clone Wars from [lego-star-wars-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars-3) to [lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've renamed it to [lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars).